# Question about specific placemenet of const keyword in overloaded -> operator

Tags: c++, overloading

Consider the following "smart pointer" like class. It holds a pointer to another class that has implemented a virtual copy constructor `clone()`.

I want to overload the `operator ->`. My source shows two implementations, a `const` and non-`const` one - which I'm fine with. I understand that the latter `const` means it cannot make changes to the underlying field variables and the former that the return type is `const`. But what does the keyword between the return type and operator mean? - i.e. the middle one.

```
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(const SomeClass& inner)   {DataPtr = inner.clone();}
    ~MyClass() {delete DataPtr;}
    SomeClass* operator->() {return DataPtr;} 
    const SomeClass* const operator->() const {return DataPtr;}
private:
    SomeClass* DataPtr;
};
```

Comment: 1) "_But what does the keyword between the return type and operator mean?_" It is not between return type, and operator. It is part of the return type. 2) Const pointer to const SomeClass, instead of just const pointer to SomeClass?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Oh my.. Thanks! I got stuck down the road of thinking it somehow acted on the operator, which I of course couldn't make sense of.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not  sure I follow. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can reduce your case to `const int foo();` or `int const foo();`.

Comment: simple example: `const int foo(); int a = foo(); a = 5;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const SomeClass* const`

In this case, `const` is part of the return type. This can be valid C code. As always, read from right to left:

- `const` pointer to a `const` `SomeClass` instance.

This means that the pointer itself is `const`, and that the pointee cannot be modified through it. Note that the rightmost `const` is useless in your example as you're returning by value: it's the same as returning `const int`.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, the equivalent syntax would be  `const SomeClass* operator->() const` right?

Answer (score 1):

> and the former that the return type is const

Actually, no. The former (i.e. the first const of `const SomeClass* const`) means that the return type is pointer to const. This means that the pointed object cannot be modified using the pointer.

> But what does the keyword between the return type and operator mean?

It is part of the type.

const in a type name always applies to what is on the left side (except when the const is the left most token, in which case it applies to the right). In this case, there is an `*` on the left side of the const that we're considering. This means that the pointer is const i.e. the pointer itself cannot be modified.

It is not sensible to return a non-class type const value (in this case, a const pointer), because the constness has has no effect on the behaviour of the program. Some compilers will issue a warning if you do this. I recommend removing the const in question.

Even for class types, while it might make a difference in some case, I don't know of any practical use case for returning a const value. Returning a pointer or a reference to const does make sense however.